# Find all integers a so that the sequence (Xn) satisfies the condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, contest-math, recursion

Let ($x_n$) be a sequence integers defined as such:
For all $n>1$ $x_{n+2} =2x_{n+1}x_{n} - x_{n+1} - x_n +1$ ,
$x_0=a$ , $x_1=2$

Find all integers a such that for all $n>1$ the number
$2x_{3n} -1$ is a square of a natural number.

Found this one in an old russian textbook for olympiad practice, couldn't solve it and the author didn't include the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_n=2x_n-1$. Then $y_0=2a-1$, $y_1=5$, and
$$y_{n+2}= y_{n+1}y_n.$$
The power $v_5(y_n)$ with which $5$ occurs in $y_n$ is then governed by a Fibonacci-like recursion 
$$v_5(y_{n+2})=v_5(y_{n+1})v_5(y_{n}) $$
where we only know $v_5(y_1)=1$ exactly and $v_5(y_0)=v_5(2a-1)$ is some finite integer.
We conclude that
$$v_5(y_n)=v_5(2a-1)\cdot F_{n-1} +F_n.\tag1$$
For all other primes $p\ne 5$, we find
$$v_p(y_n)=v_p(2a-1)\cdot F_{n-1}.\tag2$$
We want that both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are even whenever $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $>3$. 
One readily verifies, that for such $n$, $F_n$ is even and $F_{n-1}$ is odd. We conclude that the desired property holds iff $v_(2a-1)$ is even for all $p$, i.e., $$2a-1\text{ is a perfect square},$$
or in other words, $$a=\frac{(2k-1)^2+1}2=2k(k-1)+1$$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thank you for that contribution.